# Can't see changes in Visual Studio Add-in after rebuild

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I am making an Add in for Visual Studio. Every time a change something in the code or design, I have to restart Visual Studio in order to see changes from Tools -> My_Add_In. I try to rebuild a project and still can't see changes without restarting. Is it a way to run my add in without restarting VS?

Comment: I think I found a problem. In Project Properties Build output was set for bin\Debug instead of bin\ .. I changed output to bin\ and I see changes, but it gives me another error while building: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Project1.dll" to "bin\Project1.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Project1.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you used the addin wizard the plugin will be started from the "MyAddin1-For Testing.Addin" file. It is located in the plugin folder. So "Start Debugging" will open a new Visual Studio instance and load the plugin. If you now close both Visual Studio windows, and open it again your plugin will be loaded in the VS instance you use for coding. So you should rename the MyAddin1-For Testing.Addin if you start the the VS instance you use for coding. After that rename it back.